# Setting library path for dll which is in jar file

Tags: java, swing, dll, desktop-application

In my netbeans desktop application i kept .dll files of Rxtx inside the project. Can i set library path for those .dll files.

This is project hierarchy

projectName

- pacakge1

  ```
   rxtx
            rxtxSerial.dll
            rxtxParall.dll
  ```
- package2
- META-INF

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a java code loads a native library (generally done via `System.load()`), this call is a native call to OS. The actual loading of DDL is done by OS (Please correct me if this is not so). In that case the OS would need a *definite path* to the dll to be loaded. If the DLLs are inside some jar file, the OS does not recognize jar files structure (it can only be interpreted by java runtime) so those files wont be found when packaged inside jar.

Just an example, for a standard JDK distribution, all the class files are packaged in `rt.jar` file, whereas all the native code DLLs (sockets, awt etc ) are at a separate location (`jre/bin`).  So my suggestion would be, create two set of files one jar and other DLLs. Create a ZIP archive. Now if  anybody who needs to use this, have to unzip, keep jar in classpath and DLLs in PATH.

Comment: Yes, DLL loading is done by OS and if the DLLs are stored inside a jar, then they must be extracted somewhere into the (Windows) file system before they can be loaded. There's no way around it.